# Powershell: How to reference the columns in a select

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm using PowerShell 5.1 to iterate through a list of computers from active directory, and I'm struggling with something that should be simple.

In the code below, I'm selecting the name and description for each computer in a foreach loop. How should I reference the name and description individually inside the loop?

```
    $OU=@('OU=...') 
    $computers = $OU | foreach {Get-ADComputer -filter {
    Name -notlike 'xxx*' 
    -and Name -notlike 'yyy*' 
    } -searchbase $_  -Properties description | Select name, description }
 
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
      $computerName = $computer | select -ExpandProperty name
      $computerDescription =  $computer | select -ExpandProperty description
      Write-Host "Host: $computerName [$computerDescription]"
    }
```

I was able to  get it to work using `select -ExpandProperty` , but this seems unnecessarily complicated. The $computer variable holds key/value pairs like this:

```
@{name=ABCDE12345; description=Kiosk PC [Domain Separated]}
```

I tried using dot notation `$computer.name $computer.description` but the dot was ignored and treated as text.

I have tried googling this, but I'm new to PowerShell and not sure how to phrase my question!

Comment: `"Host: $($computer.name) [$($computer.description)]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using dot notation `$computer.name $computer.description` but the dot was ignored and treated as text.

String expansion only applies to simple variable references. If you want to dereference properties inside a string expression, you'll need the subexpression operator `$()`:

```
"Host: $($computer.name) [$($computer.description)]"
```

PowerShell will now evaluate the subexpressions separately when resolving the string value

Comment: Thank you! I lost a few hours trying to figure this out. My script looks for a specific running executable on any of our systems and terminates it. I thought finding and killing processes would be the hard part, but I had that in minutes!